# One to many join in python with zero fill in repeated record created due to one to many join

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframe df1, & df2.The relationship is one to many & I need 0 instead of repeating same value of table with 1 relationship.Here is the sample of my two dataframes & the datafrane after merging
df1 looks like

```
Class  Section  ID   Subject    Score
 I       A       12  Maths       70
 I       A       12  Chemistry   85 
 I       A       12  Physics     75
 I       A       16  Maths       70
 I       A       16  Chemistry   85 
 I       A       16  Physics     75
 I       A       16  Arts        65
 I       B       14  Arts        60
```

& df2 looks like

```
Class  Section  ID   Subject    Score
 I       A       12  Total       230
 I       A       16  Total       230
 I       A       16  Total       65 
 I       B       14  Total       65
```

I would like to join these two tables using matching columns Class, Section,ID & I need the final table looks like after joining

```
   Class  Section  ID   Subject  Score Total
 I       A       12  Maths       70    230 
 I       A       12  Chemistry   85    0
 I       A       12  Physics     75    0
 I       A       16  Maths       70    230
 I       A       16  Chemistry   85    65  
 I       A       16  Physics     75    0
 I       A       16  Arts        65    0
 I       B       14  Arts        60    60
```

Can you suggest me how should I do this using python 3.X

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, but each group can be enumerated with [groupby cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) then the enumeration can be used for [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
cols = ['Class', 'Section', 'ID']
df3 = (
    df1.merge(df2.drop('Subject', axis=1)  # Remove unneeded column from df2
              .rename(columns={'Score': 'Total'}),  # Fix column name for output
              left_on=[*cols, df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()],
              right_on=[*cols, df2.groupby(cols).cumcount()],
              how='left')
        .drop('key_3', axis=1)  # remove added merge key
)
```

`df3`:

```
  Class Section  ID    Subject  Score  Total
0     I       A  12      Maths     70  230.0
1     I       A  12  Chemistry     85    NaN
2     I       A  12    Physics     75    NaN
3     I       A  16      Maths     70  230.0
4     I       A  16  Chemistry     85   65.0
5     I       A  16    Physics     75    NaN
6     I       A  16       Arts     65    NaN
7     I       B  14       Arts     60   65.0  # This should be 65 from df2
```

Then [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to fix the `Total` column:

```
df3['Total'] = df3['Total'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

`df3`:

```
  Class Section  ID    Subject  Score  Total
0     I       A  12      Maths     70    230
1     I       A  12  Chemistry     85      0
2     I       A  12    Physics     75      0
3     I       A  16      Maths     70    230
4     I       A  16  Chemistry     85     65
5     I       A  16    Physics     75      0
6     I       A  16       Arts     65      0
7     I       B  14       Arts     60     65
```

---

DataFrame constructors:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Class': ['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
    'Section': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'ID': [12, 12, 12, 16, 16, 16, 16, 14],
    'Subject': ['Maths', 'Chemistry', 'Physics', 'Maths', 'Chemistry',
                'Physics', 'Arts', 'Arts'],
    'Score': [70, 85, 75, 70, 85, 75, 65, 60]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Class': ['I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
    'Section': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'ID': [12, 16, 16, 14],
    'Subject': ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'Total'],
    'Score': [230, 230, 65, 65]
})
```